# How to hide table when blank

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I'm trying to hide a table but can't get it to work.

I'm pulling data from a lookup table and for records without any matches I want to hide these rows so that only populated tables/rows show.

I tried doing this using the following code:

```
IF EMPTY(@old_product1) OR EMPTY(@old_product2) .... THEN

    SET @hide = "display:none;"

ENDIF

<Span Style="%%=v(@hide)=%%">
    <table>
        .....
    </table>
</span>
```

Comment: Looks correct to me. I assume your IF statement is contained in an AMPscript block? Also, what is the `....` for? Is this additional conditions? I would try printing the values of `@old_product1` and `@old_product2` to confirm if they are empty.

Comment: .... just the rest of the HTML code. i have just recoded this to be inline and it seems to work. %%[IF EMPTY(@old_product1) THEN]%% <span style="%%=v(@hide)=%%'> %%{endif]%%  also another question is there an easy way to dedupe based on product?

Answer (score 1):

Slightly off - see below:

```
IF EMPTY(@old_product1) OR EMPTY(@old_product2) .... THEN

    SET @hide = 'style="display:none;"'

ENDIF

<span "%%=v(@hide)=%%">
    <table>
        .....
    </table>
</span>
```

with using single quotes, you can include the double quotes inside of your string. I don't know why, but adding style declarations into an existing style attribute never seems to work correctly for me either. I also prefer it declared this way as it can reduce unnecessary code in the non-empty version as well as increase processing speed.

There is actually an even more efficient way to do this. See below:

```
%%[IF EMPTY(@old_product1) OR EMPTY(@old_product2) .... THEN]%%

---- Any content you might want to add if empty ---

%%[ELSE]%%

    table>
        .....
    </table>

%%[ENDIF]%%
```

This will only include that table if the variables are not empty. Removing the need to hide it.

Comment: Your "more efficient" way is much better.  Last thing you want is an email client ignoring the "display:hide" and displaying it anyhow.